# Python - Webscrape hidden chars show in len how do i remove these?

Tags: python, string, selenium, web-scraping, integer

I have used:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(.//span[@class = "x"])')[0].text
```

The information it pulls is correct but it adds spaces that show in the HTML as  as `"&#8237"` from the website im scaping.

How do I remove these so I can turn the str in to a int with as this is stopping me at the moment.

I have tried `.strip` and `.replace` with no luck.

Heres the raw HTML

```
<span class="coordinateX">(&#8237;‭−&#8237;‭52&#8236;&#8237;‬‬</span>
```

when I print this string i get (-52 but when I `len()` it I get 8 instead of 4 due to these hidden characters.

Thanks
Mark.

Comment: Try RegEx, 'import re' then create a pattern to detect and remove the items you don't want.

Comment: Can you give an example ? I don't see any reason why `replace` won't work here!

Comment: I cant see what the textis to say why it wont work. What does the result of that command give you, show us the string you're trying to work with. Check out my answer below, see if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try regex?

```
import re

string = 'Here is some string to&#8237test'

string = re.sub(r'(&#\d\d\d\d)',' ', string)

print(string)

>>> 'Here is some string to test'
```

re.sub says, if you find this regex pattern r'(&#\d\d\d\d)', replace it with a ' ', and do this search in the 'string' variable.

Resources

https://pythex.org/ - for creating and testing patterns

Learning material

https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm

Comment: Hello,This doesnt seem to work heres the raw HTML
```
<span class="coordinateX">(&#8237;‭−&#8237;‭52&#8236;&#8237;‬‬</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The relevant HTML would have helped us to debug the issue in a better way. However, you can use [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method instead of `text` property as follows:

```
myText = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(.//span[@class = "x"])')[0].get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I tried .get_attribute() and is still has the same issue len() brings back 8 but it should only actually be 4.

Comment: @Mark Can you update the question with the relevant HTML for further analysis?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was creating "Travian" inactive players search to scan all villages at the server :D.
I am pretty sure you are facing same problem as I did.

```
        text = text.Replace((char)8237, ' ');
        text = text.Replace((char)8236, ' ');
        text = text.Replace('(', ' ');
        text = text.Replace(')', ' ');
        text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\s+", "");
        text = text.Replace('−', '-');
        int number = int.Parse(text);
```

I am sorry for sharing my answer in C# language but this code:

1. replaces characters &#8236, &#8236 and parenthesis with white spaces.
2. removes whitespaces
3. Next line is super important because that "minus sign" you are working with is not in numeric format. You must replace '−'symbol with ALT+45 symbol '-' to convert successfully.
4. Converts modified text to coordinates integer.

Another way to get coordinates is to use href="/karte.php?x=83&y=-10" attribute
You may try to get this link as string from browser. Then extract x and y from it

Comment: I really think the OP needs solutions in Python, not C#. Their question isn't as detailed as it could be, but they didn't mention anything about working with / being able to incorporate C# code into their project